# How to open the Run dialog box with a file already in the box

Tags: batch-file

Crappy title, but the thing I want to do is this:

Open the windows dialog box from cmd
I already know how to do this
But I was wandering if I could open it and have a set file selected

E.g. `powershell -c (New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application").FileRun()` opens the dialog box

But I want:

`powershell -c (New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application").FileRun("C:\<file_location>")` opens the dialog box with "C:\" automatically inserted

Comment: Set your path in the RunMRU at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.  I am by no means a powershell guy.  I just Google searched.

```
powershell -c (New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application").FileRun();$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;$wshell.SendKeys('C:\temp')
```

Comment: To expand onto this you can add `;$wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')` onto the end of your line of code. This will automatically press enter.